# Generate compiler/linker flags for gcc, given library

Tags: c, unix, gcc, clang, ld

### Problem

Is there a way I can generate linker/compiler flags for function libraries, given one or more source files?

### Details

Software specifications:

- Operating System: `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x86_64`
- Kernel: `5.11.0-27-generic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a handy tool you can use to generate compiler/linker flags for your code. It's called `pkg-config`, and you can use it like so:

```
gcc file.c $(pkg-config --cflags <library>) $(pkg-config --libs <library>)
```

I'd recommend defining a variable containing all of your dependencies, then using a shell script or other means to generate the `pkg-config` output for that library.